# Why does this sentence use the negative present progressive of 経つ to talk about the past?

Tags: grammar, nuances

「卵やステーキを最後に食べてから2日しか経っていませんが、もう一度食べたいです！」

I think is means: "It's only been 2 days (only two days have passed) since I've eaten eggs and steak, but I want to eat it again!"

If I'm right, then it's talking about time that has passed, but doesn't use the any sort of past tense, so I'm confused as to why that is. I know しか is used with a negative, but why does it use 経っていません instead of 経ちませんでした (past negative). If it's not something that's easily explainable, do you know of any sources that may clarify this for me?

Also, looking at example sentences that use 経つ, I see different conjugations that use both past and present, but the English translation makes them seem to mean the same thing. I've been told that they mean the same thing, and that some are natural, while others are not, but I can't seem to figure out why different conjugations are used to mean the same thing.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `２つしか食べていません` and  `２つしか食べませんでした`?

Comment: Related to [Problem Understanding the 経つ Verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87417/43676) (for the use of the present tense).

Comment: Doesn't the first one mean something like "I've only eaten two" and the second means something like "I only ate two" or something like that?

Comment: Yes, and that applies to 経つ as well. There is nothing specific to that verb. The specificity is in the use of the present tense to refer to time that has already passed, and I suspect your question is a duplicate of the one I provided the link of.

Comment: I'm currently reading it over, and it seems to be answering my question, so thanks for the help!