# What is the tense of 「卒業して5年になる」?

Tags: grammar, て-form, tense

I was studying the te-form in depth and found out that it can be used as a starting point ([起点](https://yousei.arc-academy.net/manbow/index.php/term/detail/857)) and a Japanese friend of mine told me that it is the same as ～てから; just an omission of から. It seems to be common to be used as a set phrase like `something + して + time + になる`, like the exemple sentence in the title, or the one inside the link (`結婚して十年になる`). When I asked to my friend why なる instead of なった or なっている, they just translated to "we have been married for 10 years".

Can the "present tense" of Japanese verbs be used the same way as the present perfect continuous in English? It's not very common to find other information about the usage of the present tense and present perfect continuous in Japanese (*if you know it, even written in Japanese, let me know*), only that it can represent habits or the future tense. It doesn't seem to make sense to be in the future tense, and habits don't seem to work well here too. That's why I thought it could be `なっている`.

I [found](https://yousei.arc-academy.net/manbow/index.php/term/detail/418) that stative verbs like ある and いる (and that also includes なる, probably) can be used in the present tense to well... indicate a state.

> 動詞では状態動詞（「ある」「いる」など）では「今家にいる」「明日は家にいる」のように、現在・未来の両方を表すことができるので「現在・未来形」と呼ばれることもある。

Then, what would be the difference between なる and なっている?

Comment: Perhaps related [Problem Understanding the 経つ Verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87417)

Comment: Thanks! It is related and helped me a lot. That topic seems to be somewhat specific, so I would also like to read someone else's opinion.

Comment: If you'd like to know テイル in general, [this series of articles](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/teiru-zentai) would help. By the definition there, なる is not a 状態動詞 (because なっている is possible; あっている/いている are basically not).

Comment: @sundowner Thank you **SO MUCH**! I actually found that website some days ago because I wanted to study んです in depth. I didn't took that website too seriously about the possibility of other topics because there wasn't a summary and it seemed I had to pay for some lessons, but other free lessons are at the left part of the website as you scroll it down. There is a series of [テンス](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/tense) and [アスペクト](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/aspect), as well as other interesting topics! I think with those lessons I'll understand more about what I was asking here.